# Arc length of gamma function curve equals its value - coincidence?

Tags: gamma-function, arc-length

While perusing Wolfram Alpha, I stumbled upon a strange curiosity involving the Gamma function:

> The *arc length* of $\Gamma(x + 1)$ from 1 to $x$ *very* closely equals the numeric value of $\Gamma(x)$.

Examples for $x = $...

1. (Not evaluated)
2. $\Gamma(2+1) = 2;~~~~~~$  Arc length of $\Gamma(x+1)$ from 1 to 2 = [1.442...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+gamma(x%2B1)+from+1+to+2)
3. $\Gamma(3+1) = 6;~~~~~~$  Arc length of $\Gamma(x+1)$ from 1 to 3 = [5.5846...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+gamma(x%2B1)+from+1+to+3)
4. $\Gamma(4+1) = 24;~~~~$ Arc length of $\Gamma(x+1)$ from 1 to 4 = [23.6185...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+gamma(x%2B1)+from+1+to+4)
5. $\Gamma(5+1) = 120;~~$ Arc length of $\Gamma(x+1)$ from 1 to 5 = [119.625...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+gamma(x%2B1)+from+1+to+5)
6. $\Gamma(6+1) = 720;~~$ Arc length of $\Gamma(x+1)$ from 1 to 6 = [719.626...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+gamma(x%2B1)+from+1+to+6)

### Question

> **Is this an unusual or seldom-discussed-but-fascinating mathematical coincidence?**

Or, am I missing some obvious numerical relationship staring me right in my eyes? ;-)

P.S. I *am* aware of how the gamma function extends factorial to $\mathbb{R}$, but with the $+1$ offset.

Answer (score 1):

Your arc length can be written as $$L=\int_1^x \sqrt{\Gamma'^2(t)+1}\,dt$$ where $\Gamma'^2(t)$ is the derivative of $\Gamma(t)$. When $x$ is large enough, $\Gamma'^2(t)\gg 1$, the integral is dominated by the large values of $t$, then $$L\sim \int_1^x\Gamma'(t)\,dt\sim \Gamma(x)-1\sim \Gamma(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial property.

For any function with a large derivative,

$$\int\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}\,dx\approx\int f'(x)\,dx=f(x)+C.$$

For example with the exponential $e^x$,

$$\int\sqrt{1+e^{2x}}\,dx=\sqrt{1+e^{2x}}+\text{arcoth}\sqrt{1+e^{2x}}+C$$

which is asymptotic to $e^x$.

[image]

Intuitively, this is because the horizontal displacement brings a neglectable contribution when the curve gets close to vertical.